# returning a value with a constructor in java

Tags: java, object, constructor

Alright So This is an Assignment, so Dont help me too much... i just need to return a DnaSequence the object. and thats it. Uhm heres the constructor

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.String;

public class DnaSequence {

  public char[] dna;

  public DnaSequence(char[] dna) {
    String str = String.valueOf(dna);
    str.replaceAll("[^ATCG]", "");
    dna = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < dna.length; i++) {
      this.dna[i] = dna[i];
    }
    return dna;
  }
}
```

I will be using io.file and lang.string later.

And here is the Main (for testing )

```
public class DnaSequencetEST {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] bases = { 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A' };
    DnaSequence seq = new DnaSequence(bases);
    System.out.println(seq);//Should print "GATTACA"
  }
}
```

And below is a link to what my finish result should do and or look like.(just for fun if you wanna look at it)
http://jeff.cis.cabrillo.edu/datasets/12j_dnasequence/DnaSequence.html

So DnaSequence.java:14 error: incompatible types: unexpected return value 
return dna:
        ^
So yea Thats what ive been staring at for like 5 hours, Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Constructors aren't supposed to return something.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the downvotes. The question is clear, with examples, and is easily answerable. The fact that the poster does not know basic concepts of Java is no reason to downvote, it's the reason he is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, two hints for you:

- Constructors don't return values. They *create* objects.
- If you want to print a custom object you should define a specfic *toString* method to instruct Java how should the object be displayed. [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method) an example.

Comment: A slight correction: constructors don't create objects. The jvm does that. And then the constructor is called to initialize the freshly created object.

Comment: Thank You Very much, Worked perfectly : )

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is for initializing object internal state. Here that would logically be the `char[] dna` field (and don't make fields `public` just "because"). Next, a `String` is immutable; so `str.replaceAll("[^ATCG]", "");` without an assignment is pointless (but you can chain it before calling to `toCharArray()`). You need to override `toString()` for the behavior you want. And you can simply pass a `char[]` to the `String` constructor. Like,

```
public class DnaSequence {
    private char[] dna;

    public DnaSequence(char[] dna) {
        this.dna = new String(dna).replaceAll("[^ATCG]", "").toCharArray();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new String(dna);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, haha, thats a nice line of code, i didnt know i could call so many methods in one line.

Comment: @JacobBurgess [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the requirements but to pass that test you just need to implement the `toString()` on `DnaSequence` and return the DNA sequence.
Note the `System.out.println` will always call the `toString` if the object passed is an `Object`.

Solution:

```
public class DnaSequence {

  public final String dna;

  public DnaSequence(char[] dna) {
    this.dna = String.valueOf(dna).replaceAll("[^ATCG]", "");
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.dna;
  }

}
```